# How To Implement Custom Password Hashing in Django?

Tags: python, django, base64, passwords

So my manager has asked me to implement Base64 Password Encryption for our django website. I can't find any base64 hashing algo in django.contrib.auth.hashers. So, I figured that I'd have to write my own Hasher module. Problem is, I don't know how. I have tried reading the django documentation but its still unclear to me. I just need my User's Passwords to be stored using Base64 Encryption in the database. Also, I need my Custom User Authentication to work accordingly.

Here's my User Model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from .managers import UserManager

class User( AbstractUser ) : 

    email = models.EmailField( verbose_name = 'Email Address', unique = True, null = False )
    username = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__( self ) : return self.get_username()
```

Here's my User Manager:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

class UserManager( BaseUserManager ) : 

    def create_user( self, email = None, password = None, first_name = None, last_name = None ) :
        
        try : 

            user = self.model( email = self.normalize_email( email ) )
            user.set_password( password )
            user.is_active = True

            user.first_name = first_name
            user.last_name = last_name
                
            user.save( using = self._db )
            return user

        except Exception as e : raise Exception( e )
    


    def create_staffuser( self, email, password ) :

        try : 

            staffuser = self.create_user( email, password )
            staffuser.is_staff = True
            staffuser.save( using = self._db )

            return staffuser

        except Exception as e : raise Exception( e )



    def create_superuser( self, email = None, password = None ) :

        try : 

            superuser = self.create_staffuser( email, password )
            superuser.is_superuser = True
            superuser.save( using = self._db )

            return superuser

        except Exception as e : raise Exception( e )
```

Here's my backends.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
from .models import User



class AuthBackend( ModelBackend ) : 

    def authenticate( email = None, password = None ) : 

        try : 

            user = User.objects.get( email = email )
            if user.check_password( password ) : return user
            else : raise Exception( 'Password Does Not Match...' )

        except Exception as e : raise Exception( str( e ) )
```

Comment: Are you referring to [base-64 encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html)? What you're describing isn't encryption.

Comment: Exactly. Please do not do this. base64 is instantly reversible and does not protect the passwords in any way if the data is stolen. Instead, passwords should be hashed using an algorithm designed for password storage (such as Argon2) using Django's built-in methods.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/passwords

Comment: I understand that this is not a secure approach but my manager wants me to build it this way. So I have to! I just want to see an illustration of how to store passwords in base64 "encoding" in django